# logs from entity framework generation

Tags: entity-framework, auto-generate

I'm using EF to communicate with my database.
I made a function import mapping so I can call a Stored Procedure. By on run time I get a error saying "Method not found" referring the method that was created to invoke the SP.
I'm assuming that is an error during the generation on run time.

The question is: Is there any way to see what's going on during the execution time generation so I can find the problem?

Comment: Maybe good to mention that this is not a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11760752/861716).

Comment: This is about the same error but I want to know a complete different thing.